# Изменение стилей при сравнении ворд документов c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

Возникла необходимость реализовать версионность вордовских документов. С помощью Interop.Word удалось сравнить два вордовских документа и вернуть на выход третий - с изменениями/удалениями.

```
var doc = wordApp.CompareDocuments(file1, file2, MsWord.WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationNew,
                    MsWord.WdGranularity.wdGranularityWordLevel, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, "", false);
```

Но возникла проблема, удаленные участки текста помечаются красным зачеркнутым стилем, а вставленный - просто красным. Найти решения по изменению стилей, чтобы удаленный текст помечался просто красным, а вставленный зеленым - не удалось. Поэтому прошу совета, как и в какую сторону копать)

Comment: Это настройки отображения в самом word-е а не стили. [Как поменять написано тут](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-48c80bb3-458c-4abb-8e21-25f9bac47484)

Comment: Возможно их тоже можно задать через Interop, я не знаю, но это настройка приложения, а не конкретного документа.

Comment: Попробую копнуть туда. Т.е по идее, если я свои стили настрою -> сохраню их в документе -> потом открою док на другой машине - стили будут стандарные?

Comment: Если вы про стиль выделения различий, то да будут разные.